# Rails, SyntaxError Exception: servers_controller.rb:18: unterminated string meets end of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In Rails, 
I found an error `SyntaxError Exception: servers_controller.rb:18: unterminated string meets end of file` when I written a wanted to pass multiple code below.
Commands as into server to execute one by one.

```
 all_commands="date;ls -ltr;";

 all_commands.split(";").each do |cmd_2run|  
   puts cmd_2run  
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extra `.` before `each` (and spurious semicolon after the `all_commands` definition).

```
> all_commands = "date;ls -ltr"
> all_commands.split(";").each do |cmd_2run|
*   puts cmd_2run
* end
date
ls -ltr
```

The syntax error doesn't appear related to the code you posted; there's no unterminated string.

Comment: Thanks dave, I removed .. from each issue was due to `date;ls -ltr` string; semicolon was the reason for my error. I resolved that using "\;" as in above solution. .. `all_commands="date\;ls -ltr\;";`

Comment: @ror_master Then your question does not provide all the information--you don't need to escape semicolons in Ruby strings, as my output shows.